# MongoDB: mongorestore failing for small database

Tags: mongodb, mlab, database

I am setting up a Mongo DB database on mongolab. I have 2 small documents in a single collection in my local db server, that I want to upload. I used `mongodump` to export that to a `collection.bson` and `collection.metadata.json` file

When I use `mongorestore` I get an error:

`Failed:database.collection: error restoring from /tmp/mongodump/database/collection.bson: insertion error: EOF`

`collection.bson` is less than 2KB. My research shows that this error shows up when your database is huge, but not very small. I can't get anything for my situation. The common solution of using `--batchSize 1` results in the same issue.

After I run mongorestore the collection does exist on the remote, but it is empty (0 documents)

How can I get my tiny local db up on my remote server (on MongoLab).

I am locally running mongo3.4, but my MongoLab instance is 3.2.13. I'm wondering if the problem is the mismatch of versions?

mongorestore command:

`mongorestore -h ds111882.mlab.com:11882 -d database -u username -p password /tmp/mongodump/database`

mongodump

`mongodump -d database -o /tmp/mongodump`

Additional info: I imported the mongodump I created into another local database (also running 3.4) and it worked just fine, but restoring to the mongolab server causes the error.

Also a `bsondump` of the generated `collection.bson` file creates a json file with the correct 2 documents.

Comment: Can you show the mongodump command that was used?

Comment: @dilsingi Added, plus some additional information

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, it is an issue with versions. My schema was using the Decimal128 type, which isn't supported in 3.2. Downgrading to Double (didn't need Decimal128 anyway) fixed the issue.